# C++ struct member functions definitions have differences if they are defined outside the struct body ?

Tags: c++, struct, inline, member

A C++ question about struct member functions.

What is the difference between `f1()` and `f2()` except their names ?

```
 struct F{
   int f1(){
      return 0;  
    }
    int f2();    
 }; 
 int F::f2(){
     return 0;
 }
```

May I say `f1()` is inline but `f2()` is not ?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by *inline*, but yes, in the context of how it's defined that's fine.

Comment: It is inline according to definition, but the compiler reserves the right to inline it or not (don't count on that it will).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are correct that `f1` is inline and `f2` is not, but its not **just** because it was defined inside the class. `f2` could also be inline if it was defined as

```
inline int F::f2() {
    return 0;
}
```

The C++11 spec section 9.3 says that `f1` is "defined in its class definition" and `f2` is "defined outside of its class definition."  It then states that any function defined inside its class definition is inline, while functions defined outside of its class definition must be explicitly marked as inline (like in my example above), or else they are non-inline (like your `f2`).

Inside the class definition vs. outside the definition is unimportant, other than making functions implicitly inline.  The concept of inside a class definition and outside a class definition only appears in 9.3.2-9.3.5, while the broader concept of "inline" appears in other parts of the spec.